# Spark Compatible Data Quality Framework for Narrow Data

Tags: apache-spark, data-quality, great-expectations, amazon-deequ

I'm trying to find an appropriate data quality framework for very large amounts of time series data in a [narrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) format.

Image billions of rows of data that look kinda like this:

| Sensor | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12251 | 12 |
| B | 12262 | "A" |
| A | 12261 | 13 |
| A | 12271 | 13 |
| C | 12273 | 5.4545 |

There are hundreds of thousands of sensors, but for each timestamp only a very small percentage send values.

I'm building  Data Quality Monitoring for this data that checks some expectations about the values (e.g. whether the value falls within the expected range for a given sensor, there are tens of thousands of different expectations). Due to the size of the data and existing infrastructure the solution has to be run on Spark.  I would like to build this solution on an (ideally open source) data quality framework, but cannot find anything appropriate.

I've looked into Great Expectations and Deequ, but these fundamentally seem to be build for "wide data" where the expectations are defined for columns. I could theoretically reshape (pivot) my data to this format, but it would be a very expensive operation and result in an extremly sparse table that is awkward to work with (or require sampling on the time and in this way a loss of information).

Does anyone know of an existing (spark compatible) framework for such time series data in narrow format? Or can point me to best practices how to apply Deequ/Great Expectations in such a setting?

Comment: do you really need an expectation for each sensor? Usually people work with sensor classes or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `github.com/canimus/cuallee`
It is an open-source framework, that supports the Observation API to make testing on billions of records, super-fast, and less resource greedy as pydeequ. Is intuitive, and easy to use.

Comment: it won't fit into requirements for row-level checks...

Comment: I had a similar challenge for a dataset that received pricing quotes for FX trades. As mentioned in the original question, there is no `transpose` in spark for good reason, as it is a very expensive, memory intensive computation, therefore collecting and structuring the information in a different layout could be the option.