# Spark Data - Rule Validation

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have spark application ( JAVA ) in which IoT data is sent from Kafka to Spark, where the data should be checked against some validation / rules and take necessary actions.

For ex: IoT sends temperature & Humidity and I need to check if it is within user defined threshold, if yes, just proceed or else take action ( send mail / call webhook ).

I came across [databricks-dataframe-rule-engine](https://github.com/databrickslabs/dataframe-rules-engine), which mostly similar to my requirement. But it is not upto date ( as per the last git commit ). Is there any other library/way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although I've not attempted to use it via Java, [Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/) is regularly updated and has rules defined as sql. [disclaimer - it's my lib]

There was another SO on [narrow sensor data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110716/spark-compatible-data-quality-framework-for-narrow-data) quality that sounds similar, for which there doesn't seem to be a simple / obvious solution.  If that's your use case as well there are pieces of support in Quality but not really for a streaming case (where you'd need state and cut-offs) but it's not a core focus.